# Angular material mat-slide-toggle on keyboard Enter

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an angular material mat-slide-toggle. I'm unable to toggle the button using tab + enter on keyboard.

```
 <mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

How to toggle button on pressing Enter on keyboard.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axf6wk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.html)

Comment: You should use Space Bar to toggle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add (keydown.enter) event to detect enter button click. Also you need to bind variable with mat slide toggle checked input to on off toggle button.

In your HTML file:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="checked" (keydown.enter)="onEnter()">Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

In your .ts file:

```
export class SlideToggleOverviewExample {
  checked: boolean;

  onEnter() {
    console.log("ENTER");
    this.checked = !this.checked;
  }
}
```

Below is working demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axf6wk-zivl91

Comment: Yes, tha is correct, but the mat-slide-toggle has to have the focus, otherwise, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To catch keyboard events, I recommend HostListener.
It is simple to use and effective.

Example:

```
import { HostListener, Component } from "@angular/core";
const KEY_CODE = {
  ENTER:17,
  PLUS:187
}
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<mat-slide-toggle  [checked]="checked" >Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>`
})
class AppComponent {

  public checked = false;
  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
    handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.ENTER || event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.PLUS) {
        this.checked = true;
        }
  }

}
```

To check differnetes KEY_CODES, visit:
https://keycode.info/

More:

https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener

https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview